# No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.List Rest API Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am passing a request body to a POST request on postman similar to this:

```
 "name":"Mars",
"artifacts":[
   {
      "elements":[
         {
            "name":"carbon",
            "amount":0.5,
            "measurement":"g"
         }
      ],
      "typeName":"typeA"
   },
   {
      "elements":[
         {
            "name":"hydrogen",
            "amount":0.2,
            "measurement":"g"
         }
      ],
      "typeName":"typeB"
   }
]
```

The create method in the rest controller looks like this.

```
  @RequestMapping("/create")
  public Planet create(@RequestBody Planet data) {
      Planet mars = planetService.create(data.getName(),data.getArtifacts());
      return mars;
```

Planet and all its nested objects have a default constructor such as:

```
public Planet() {}
```

However, I am not able to create a new planet object because of lack of a default constructor. Please help!

EDIT:
Planet class

```
public class Planet {
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@Field("artifacts")
private List<Artifact> artifacts;

public Planet() {}

public Planet(String name, List<Artifact> artifacts)
{
this.name = name;
this.artifacts = artifacts;
}
//setters and getters

}
```

Artifact class:

```
public class Artifact() {
@Field("elements")
private List<Element> elements;
@JsonProperty("typeName")
private String typeName;

public Artifact() {}

public Artifact(String typeName, List<Element> elements)
{
this.typeName = typeName;
this.elements = elements;
}
}
```

Element class:

```
public class Element() {
@JsonProperty("elementName")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("amount")
private double amount;
@JsonProperty("measurement")
private String measurement;

public Element() {}

public Element(String name, double amount, String measurement)
{
//assignments
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Planet.java?

Comment: Done, posted a simplified version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand what is the issue you are facing, but i can see an error straight away so guessing that is the issue you are facing, i am going to give you a solution.

Create a class which matches your json data structure like this :

```
Class PlanetData {
    private String name;
    private List<Planet> artifacts;

    public PlanetData(String name, List<Planet> artifacts){
        name = name;
        artifacts = artifacts;
    }

    // include rest of getters and setters here.
}
```

Then your controller should look like this. Basically you needed to put `@RequestBody` to all the parameters you want to recieve from request JSON. Earlier you only put `@RequestBody` to name parameter not artifact parameter and since Request Body can be consumed only once, so you need a wrapper class to recieve the complete request body using single `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
  public String create(@RequestBody PlanetData data) {
      Planet mars = planetService.create(data.getName(),data.getArtifacts());
      return mars.toString();
  }
```

Edit : Looking at the Planet class, it also needs some modification

```
public class Planet {
private String typeName; // key in json should match variable name for proper deserialization or you need to use some jackson annotation to map your json key to your variable name.
private List<Element> elements;

public Planet() {}

public Planet(String typeName, List<Element> elements)
{
this.typeName = typeName;
this.elements = elements;
}
//setters and getters. Remember to change your setters and getter from name to typeName.

}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I am getting Cannot construct instance of `com.Planet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Comment: It is because in your Json, for Planet info your key is `typeName`, not `name`, but in your Planet class you have kept it as `name`. Check the last section of my answer, i have changed the `name` to `typeName` in your Planet class. Also, if this helped, please mark this as Answer. Thanks

Comment: typeName belongs to Artifact class

Comment: Why are you changing the name and content of classes so much. Earlier your Planet class contained name and elements and now it contains name and artifacts. Please edit your question one last time so i can align my answer with your actual class otherwise we both will get confused. Add all your classes code hiding all getter and setters.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed it now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please add your other classes as well like Elements class and Artifact Class to remove any further confusion.

Comment: I am able to create the object now, thanks. I am getting some other error, will need to create new post.

Answer (score 59):

I had that the same error when I forgot the `@RequestBody` before the parameter

```
  @RequestMapping("/create")
  public Planet create(@RequestBody Planet data) {
```

Comment: That was it! I forgot to add the annotation, I spent few minutes scratching my head without undestanding what was going on, but finally I could it solved.

Answer (score 11):

This answer too might help someone.

When you are using spring framework for your API development, you may accidently import a wrong library for RequestBody and RequestHeader annotations.

In my case, I accidently imported library,

```
io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody
```

This could arise the above issue.

Please ensure that, you are using the correct library which is

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
```

Comment: Bro you saved me. I wasted my 2 hours just because of this accidental import

Answer (score 7):

I guess, it’s trying to call `new List()` which has no constructor. Try using `ArrayList` in your signatures.

If it works this way, you have found the error. Then rethink your concept of calling methods, since you would usually want to avoid using implementations of List in method signatures

Comment: Thank you this worked but getting some strange string in the object that is created.

Comment: That was just a precise answer to your question in the subject. As I said, you should re-think your concept. Here are already a couple answers that will help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your request type is not of type GET
If so it is better not to send data as request body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should write as below:

```
...
public String create(@RequestBody JSONObject requestParams) {
      String name=requestParams.getString("name");
      List<Planet> planetArtifacts=requestParams.getJSONArray("artifacts").toJavaList(Planet.Class);
...
```

Comment: Hi, i think it is better to have a wrapper class for receiving your request body. This way API contract is very clean and clear as no one has to go through your service to actually determine what API expects. What do you think?